# How do I debug this error regarding with the string and int

Tags: java

I want to know the position of the inputted numbers so I decided to convert the String type to an int data type using parse, the source code is below:

```
public static void main (String [] Args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String x = "0" ;
    int number = Integer.parseInt(x);

    System.out.print("\nEnter 5 numbers: ");
    number = input.nextInt();

    if ((x.charAt(0) == x.charAt (4)) && (x.charAt(1) == x.charAt(3))) {
        System.out.print("The set of numbers is equal to its original value");
    } else {
        System.out.print("The set of numbers is not equal to its original value");
    }   
}
```

After I compile the file, it won't run and this error appears

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 4
>           at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
>           at activity10.main(activity10.java:12)

Comment: Your String x is '0' but you try to get value from index 4. You can use any editor debugging option..

Comment: Please reformat code in your post.

Comment: I don't get what your program is trying to do (its logic does not correspond to the output). Maybe take a step back and rethink your algorithm.

Comment: how to get x.charAt(4) while size of x is just one???

Answer (score 1):

The method `charAt(i)` returns the *i-th* character of a `String` (starting at index 0). This means that if you want to call `yourString.charAt(k)` it is necessary for `yourString` to have at least *k+1* characters.

According to your code

```
String x = "0";
```

`x` will **always be** `"0"`. So any call `x.charAt(i)` for *i > 0* will result in an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

### Update

Does the following code do what you need?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("\nEnter 5 numbers: ");
    String x = input.next();

    if ((x.charAt(0) == x.charAt (4)) && (x.charAt(1) == x.charAt(3))) {
        System.out.print("The set of numbers is equal to its original value");
    } else {
        System.out.print("The set of numbers is not equal to its original value");
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Now you type all digits in the same line.

Comment: oh i forgot, this program wants to know if the numbers inputted are a palindrome or not, so what should i do (sorry for the code it's kinda messy)

Comment: Please think about what you want the program to do. Then update your question and write down what you have already tried and what your concrete problem is at the moment. This will increase your chances of getting a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the input number using *Scanner input*

The, you would not need these lines

```
String x = "0" ;
int number = Integer.parseInt(x);
```

All you need to do is to get the numbers  first

```
int number1 = input.nextInt();
int number2 = input.nextInt();
int number3 = input.nextInt();
int number4 = input.nextInt();
int number5 = input.nextInt();
```

and then start with the comparison of numbers.

Also, You can go through some Java tutorials and then start coding as it would help you to understand the programming basics